# Pytest how to combine fixture, tmp_path and parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

I want to use `tmp_path` to create some temporary files in a fixture. The fixture returns a list of files. I want to use the list elements to parametrize a pytest. The below does not work because I cannot call the fixture directly. But if I don't call it I dont get the list values. How should I create files in a temporary path and hand their location element by element to a parametrized test?

```py
# Define a fixture that uses tmp_path to create temporary files
@pytest.fixture
def create_temp_files(tmp_path):
    # Create temporary files
    file_paths = []
    for i in range(3):
        file_path = tmp_path / f"file_{i}.txt"
        file_path.write_text(f"This is file {i}")
        file_paths.append(file_path)

    return file_paths


# Define a test function that uses the list of temporary file paths
@pytest.mark.parametrize("file_path", create_temp_files())
def test_temp_files_content(file_path):
    # Read the content of the temporary file
    content = file_path.read_text()

    assert "This is file" in content
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to parametrize the fixture using the special [`params` argument](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#parametrizing-fixtures), which can be accessed inside the fixture through the special `request` object:

```python
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=range(3))
def create_temp_files(request, tmp_path):
    file_number = request.param
    file_path = tmp_path / f"file_{file_number}.txt"
    file_path.write_text(f"This is file {file_number}")

    return file_path
```

Then you can just use the parametrized fixture in your test, resulting in a parametrized test.

```python
def test_temp_files_content(create_temp_files):
    file_path = create_temp_files
    # Read the content of the temporary file
    content = file_path.read_text()

    assert "This is file" in content
```